# Optimisation on recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

I am currently working on an algorithm and at some point I have to go through an image and group the pixels that have the same properties. I start from the top left most pixel and I use recursion: From the input pixel I can get the height adjacent pixels, if the first one has the same properties then I call the same function by passing this pixel as the input pixel.

Here is some code (please keep in mind that this is still work in progress).
The base caller:

```
// R.A.G.
for( std::vector<Cell*>::iterator iterCell = cellVec.begin();
     iterCell != cellVec.end(); ++iterCell )
{
    Cell* mother = (*iterCell);

    if( mother->visited != true )
    {
        mother->visited = true;
    }
    CheckNeighbors( mother );
}
```

The recursive function:

```
void
CheckNeighbors( Cell* mother )
{
    Cell* cell = nullptr;

    // Get the neighbours for the cell.
    //  5   6   7
    //  4   c   0
    //  3   2   1
    if( (cell=CheckCell( 1, 0, mother )) != mother )
    {
        mother = cell;
        CheckNeighbors( mother );
    }
    if( (cell=CheckCell( 1, 1, mother )) != mother )
    {
        mother = cell;
        CheckNeighbors( mother );
    }
    if( (cell=CheckCell( 0, 1, mother )) != mother )
    {
        mother = cell;
        CheckNeighbors( mother );
    }
    if( (cell=CheckCell( -1, 1, mother )) != mother )
    {
        mother = cell;
        CheckNeighbors( mother );
    }
    if( (cell=CheckCell( -1, 0, mother )) != mother )
    {
        mother = cell;
        CheckNeighbors( mother );
    }
    if( (cell=CheckCell( -1, -1, mother )) != mother )
    {
        mother = cell;
        CheckNeighbors( mother );
    }
    if( (cell=CheckCell( 0, -1, mother )) != mother )
    {
        mother = cell;
        CheckNeighbors( mother );
    }
    if( (cell=CheckCell( 1, -1, mother )) != mother )
    {
        mother = cell;
        CheckNeighbors( mother );
    }
}
```

How I check the cells:

```
Cell*
CheckCell( int x, int y, Cell* cell )
{
    // Here a cell is one pixel, but it depends on the size of the window we choose.
    // So for an image of 640*480, windowSize = 1, w = 640, h = 480
    x += cell->window.x()/windowSize;
    y += cell->window.y()/windowSize;

    // The cell at (x, y) coordinates is not in the map
    if( x < 0 || x >= w || y < 0 || y >= h ) return cell;

    // Get the neighbor cell in (x, y)
    // NB: cellVec has been filled up earlier and contains all the cells
    Cell* neighbor = cellVec.at( (y*w) + x );

    // The neighbor cell has already been visited
    if( neighbor->visited ) return cell;

    // The neighbor cell is of the same class as the mother cell
    if( neighbor->cClass != cell->cClass ) return cell;

    // Set the region number for the neighbor
    neighbor->visited = true;

    return neighbor;
}
```

So here is my problem: I am certain that this can be improve but I am wondering how.
Should I use something else that recursion ?
How can this recursion be improved ?
I read [this article](http://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/overload109.pdf) about tail call optimization, but as I cannot throw away the states of the caller in my case, this cannot be applied. But is there an other trick I could use ?

Thanks for the answers, and I hope I have been explicit enough.

NB: If I have an image that is uni-color, with a size of 640*480 and a cell size of 2*2 pixels, I have 153765 calls. And of course a segfault with a 1*1 cell size. I know that I can increase the size of the stack, but I would prefer to find another solution.

Comment: How deep can the recursion go?

Comment: Ha ha, that is a good question, I forgot about that. The problem is that if I have an image that is uni-color, with a size of 640*480 and a cell size of 2*2 pixels, I have 153765 calls. And of course a segfault with a 1*1 cell size. I know that I can increase the size of the stack, but I would prefer to find another solution.

Comment: Recursion usually entails [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). To reduce depth, you want [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Comment: "I read this article about tail call optimization ...  but as I cannot throw away the states of the caller in my case" which states are you talking about?, a tail call recursion is pretty much the same than an iterative loop.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on tail recursion to avoid stack overflow (LOL)

Comment: Yes indeed, I re implemented the algorithm with BFS using a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is a [Flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill), implemented as a [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

To improve on it, you can:

- Recode it as a [Breadth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).
- Implement Depth First Search using a stack. This is still the same idea, but using a stack instead of recursion should make your code faster and use less memory.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I am going to recode it as a BFS to check on the performance.

Answer (score 1):

you will be much faster with an iterative approach, as you alread have all elements in a vector and you can linearly run through it. This is much more cache friendly and you get rid of all the offsetting stuff

```
// Copy all elements starting from the selected cell pointed to by the iterator, if 
// they are equal to the cell
void checkAllCells(vector<Cell*> input, vector<Cell*>::iterator it; vector<Cell*> output)
{
    auto localIt = it;
    while( localIt != input.end())
    {
        if ((*localIt)->class == (*it)->class)
        {
            output.pushback(*it);
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that you don't need to do bookkeeping like `visited` etc. because starting at the first element, you will find all the others that are equal. If you then take the second element, you know, that you have been considering the previous element already

Comment: Hi, the problem is that I don't want all cells of the same class to be in the same container. I want all cells of the same class that are adjacent in the same container ! A pixel could be of the same class but not adjacent, which means that it would not be in the same container...

Comment: Then you should run a filter through the picture that is a two dimensional array of Cells. The algorithm will be similar to the above, but again, as it is iterative and going linear through memory, it will be much faster. I will try to write up some code for it...

Comment: see: http://goo.gl/IPXsd
This will only find the next neighours. If you want to find ALL adjacent elements, the BFS approach might be the easiest to implement

Comment: Thanks for the code, I am having a look at it. I think I might for the BFS approach as n.m and @MAK pointed out.